# Is there a better way to declare json variable

Tags: go

Declaring a variable of type map[string]map[string]... is not ideal, is there a better way

```
    snaps := map[string]map[string]map[string]map[string]string{
    "distros": {
        "aws": {
            "eu-west-1": {
                "snap-0": "/dev/sdm",
            },
            "eu-west-2": {
                "snap-1": "/dev/sdm",
            },
        },
    },
}

fmt.Println(snaps["distros"]["aws"]["eu-west-1"])
```

Comment: Your code is unrelated to JSON. What is the actual question. map[string]map[string].. might or might not be the best data structure for a problem. You did not state the problem. Can you clarify?

Comment: I seek alternative to using map[string]map[string]map[string]map[string]string

Comment: The code you showed can be simplified by using a simple string literal. You really have to describe the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the type `map[string]interface{}`. Since the empty interface, `interface{}`, refers to any type and therefore handles the arbitrarily nested nature of JSON.

To do this you'll have to write your literal data as a string first and then parse the string into a Go `map`.

With that in mind here is a refactor of your example:

first: `import "encoding/json"`, then

```golang
snapsStr := `{
    "distros": {
        "aws": {
            "eu-west-1" : {
                "snap-0": "/dev/sdm"
            },
            "eu-west-2": {
                "snap-1": "/dev/sdm"
            }
        }
    }
}`

var snaps map[string]interface{}

json.Unmarshal([]byte(snapsStr), &snaps)
```

And now `snaps` is as desired.

This is the most generic format for JSON data in Go and is one of the ways that the Go JSON library handles types for JSON. See these docs: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

Comment: can you please post a full example, i can't compile with map[string]interface{}, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much Henry

Comment: To represent arbitrary JSON, [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) or `map[string]json.RawMessage` is more efficient than the empty interface and can still be unmarshaled later into concrete types.